# Upload files to ftp from iOS application

Tags: objective-c, ios, ftp

I read the [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) but I need an example better than this document. I Google'd some other examples but all the sites I found ended up referring to the Apple document,  and I haven't found anything else that doesn't.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Wrote an easy to use ftp uploader for iOS and it runs on a background thread courtesy of ASIHTTPReq.

https://github.com/soulslicer/QueueFTP

Comment: awesome complement : )

Comment: I wrote this when i was a coding rookie. This is really bad technique. You should never have to do uploads using FTP tbh, and im sure there are a ton of proper libraries out there now for iOS that can natively connect to FTP rather than through an ugly PHP script

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this with [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which is very powerfull.

From their [doc](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use):

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

// Upload a file on disk
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg"
forKey:@"photo"];

// Upload an NSData instance
[request setData:imageData withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

and

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"names"];
[request addPostValue:@"George" forKey:@"names"];
[request addFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photos"];
[request addData:imageData withFileName:@"george.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photos"];
```

In your case `url` would be an FTP url, e.g.: `ftp://user:password@my.host.com`

But that won't do it for you or your requirement is to make a ftp client, Have a look at these:

- https://github.com/valentinradu/WhiteRaccoon
- https://github.com/jkichline/ACFTP
- https://github.com/jkichline/ACConnect

Comment: This project is no longer maintained.

Comment: Can we update the requests , which is already in a queue, in whiterecoon

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at [Black Raccoon](https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon) which is a light FTP file system and is actively maintained.