# Objective C - Sending recorded video -- what to send?

Tags: objective-c, video, uiimagepickercontroller

Let's say I record video via the `UIImagePickerController`, it stores the video and its path onto disk.

Now I need to send this video to a third party, it could be email attachment, FTP upload or HTTPS request.

I'm stuck on this query, what do I actually send?

Do I send the raw NSData of the media in question, do I simply upload the file?  I'm just unsure about what to actually send.

Thanks now

Comment: I think the answer could be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426939/upload-files-to-ftp-from-ios-application

Comment: Thanks, I think the AFNetwork could be used to upload it; I think its just the upload of the file itself.