# Does it possible to choose specific file(.doc,.rtf,.png and etc) from iPhone devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an requirement like: There is an **Browse button**, If i select that button  automatically navigate to  **Documents directory/ PhotoGalley/ Notes and etc..**[image]

[image]

[image]

Here i uploaded Android app images, for me also i need approach same thing, I know how to get the list of files from device but i am looking like what ever i select Browse button automatically iPhone inside data should pop up

If it is possible with sandbox , can you please help me out regarding this..

Comment: NO, iPhone is more secured... ***what you can access is within your app only, nothing more***

Comment: If i get files from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34783383/4720315  will Apple App store allow or not

Comment: this is giving your app Document directory files and not iPhone all files...

Comment: ThanQ.. @ Fahim Parkar